# Android Emulator not working. Error with gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

'A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Invalid revision: undefined

Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1.'

is the error i get when I try to run: tns run android. Not sure how to fix.

Comment: try to remove node_modules and platforms and re-install them

Answer (score 0):

Try with a new device installation or in ADV Manager wipe data

Comment: That didnt fix things. Do you have other suggestions?